# Can not MemSQL Community Edition use SnapShot?

Tags: database, in-memory-database, singlestore

1. I heard that memsql community editions do not use snapshots. Is it true?
2. If it is true that you can not use the snapshot, is there another way to do data recovery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The features which are only available in Enterprise Edition are listed here: https://docs.memsql.com/memsql-editions/latest/enterprise-edition/

If by "snapshots" you mean the BACKUP feature, that is Enterprise-only. You can use other tools to backup and restore data, such as mysqldump, but of course they have a number of disadvantages compared to the built-in BACKUP functionality.

If are are asking about snapshots as described at https://docs.memsql.com/operational-manual/v5.8/using-durability-and-recovery/, those are part of the core functionality of the database and used in both Community and Enterprise, and are used automatically (you don't need to do anything, snapshotting happens in the background).